# Snowflake JSON parsing flatten items in an without a 'key' in an array (list)

Tags: arrays, json, list, parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to parse a JSON extract from AWS textract.

```
{
  "BlockType": "CELL",
  "ColumnIndex": 2,
  "ColumnSpan": 1,
  "Confidence": 99.87053680419922,
  "Geometry": {
    "BoundingBox": {
      "Height": 0.023682409897446632,
      "Left": 0.10847073048353195,
      "Top": 0.6578078269958496,
      "Width": 0.18180404603481293
    },
    "Polygon": [
      {
        "X": 0.10847073048353195,
        "Y": 0.6578078269958496
      },
      {
        "X": 0.2902747690677643,
        "Y": 0.6578078269958496
      },
      {
        "X": 0.2902747690677643,
        "Y": 0.6814902424812317
      },
      {
        "X": 0.10847073048353195,
        "Y": 0.6814902424812317
      }
    ]
  },
  "Id": "8f1d94e9-f936-4ea9-bae8-b3e0347c5411",
  "Page": 1,
  "Relationships": [
    {
      "Ids": [
        "5b7b930f-5715-4fa6-b85b-9e2253e2b389",
        "52e9d462-5aa2-4df2-9a33-3b59e03ea256",
        "92d278f8-2d44-41ce-8cfd-35feccfba29d",
        "69121af9-3270-488b-9335-70359859f9d6",
        "827011b6-fc8c-4749-89bd-91f376eaa554",
        "dd001bd6-f146-41e0-b5b3-6afb2bf37f17",
        "a4286c8f-f7a2-4b7d-84b0-e38b7cd93225"
      ],
      "Type": "CHILD"
    }
  ],
  "RowIndex": 1,
  "RowSpan": 1
}
```

When I try to flatten using:

```
lateral flatten(input => SOURCE_CONTENTS:Relationships[0]:Ids , MODE=> 'BOTH') where SOURCE_CONTENTS:BlockType = 'CELL'
```

the where statement returns the full list of Ids. All 7 of them repeated 7 times per row. I would like to get 1st, 2nd, 3rd item in the array. 1 per row.

```
26
[ { "Ids": [ "5b7b930f-5715-4fa6-b85b-9e2253e2b389", "52e9d462-5aa2-4df2-9a33-3b59e03ea256", "92d278f8-2d44-41ce-8cfd-35feccfba29d", "69121af9-3270-488b-9335-70359859f9d6", "827011b6-fc8c-4749-89bd-91f376eaa554", ...
27
[ { "Ids": [ "5b7b930f-5715-4fa6-b85b-9e2253e2b389", "52e9d462-5aa2-4df2-9a33-3b59e03ea256", "92d278f8-2d44-41ce-8cfd-35feccfba29d", "69121af9-3270-488b-9335-70359859f9d6", "827011b6-fc8c-4749-89bd-91f376eaa554", ...
28
[ { "Ids": [ "5b7b930f-5715-4fa6-b85b-9e2253e2b389", "52e9d462-5aa2-4df2-9a33-3b59e03ea256", "92d278f8-2d44-41ce-8cfd-35feccfba29d", "69121af9-3270-488b-9335-70359859f9d6", "827011b6-fc8c-4749-89bd-91f376eaa554", ...
29
[ { "Ids": [ "5b7b930f-5715-4fa6-b85b-9e2253e2b389", "52e9d462-5aa2-4df2-9a33-3b59e03ea256", "92d278f8-2d44-41ce-8cfd-35feccfba29d", "69121af9-3270-488b-9335-70359859f9d6", "827011b6-fc8c-4749-89bd-91f376eaa554", ...
30
[ { "Ids": [ "5b7b930f-5715-4fa6-b85b-9e2253e2b389", "52e9d462-5aa2-4df2-9a33-3b59e03ea256", "92d278f8-2d44-41ce-8cfd-35feccfba29d", "69121af9-3270-488b-9335-70359859f9d6", "827011b6-fc8c-4749-89bd-91f376eaa554", ...
31
[ { "Ids": [ "5b7b930f-5715-4fa6-b85b-9e2253e2b389", "52e9d462-5aa2-4df2-9a33-3b59e03ea256", "92d278f8-2d44-41ce-8cfd-35feccfba29d", "69121af9-3270-488b-9335-70359859f9d6", "827011b6-fc8c-4749-89bd-91f376eaa554", ...
32
[ { "Ids": [ "5b7b930f-5715-4fa6-b85b-9e2253e2b389", "52e9d462-5aa2-4df2-9a33-3b59e03ea256", "92d278f8-2d44-41ce-8cfd-35feccfba29d", "69121af9-3270-488b-9335-70359859f9d6", "827011b6-fc8c-4749-89bd-91f376eaa554", ...
```

Expected output:

'5b7b930f-5715-4fa6-b85b-9e2253e2b389'

'52e9d462-5aa2-4df2-9a33-3b59e03ea256'

'92d278f8-2d44-41ce-8cfd-35feccfba29d'

'69121af9-3270-488b-9335-70359859f9d6'

'827011b6-fc8c-4749-89bd-91f376eaa554'

**EDIT:**
Since you asked about the output. What we really want it to be able to recreate a table that was extracted from AWS textract in Snowflake. This is just the first part. Getting the cell contents to return the ids that are associated with the cell. Then we could look up the contents of the cell and reconstruct the table. As you can see the "CELL" block contains columns and row references in addition to child relationships that point back to the contents of the cell.

I was trying to put this output in a where statement that held this list of children so that we could get the words associated with them. That could be the wrong approach.

For example:
if the child values '861db385-0764-4fef-a4c1-f354a5e08fce' are in the following format. I can pull up the contents of the cell including the words associated with the cell.

```
SELECT SOURCE_CONTENTS, SOURCE_CONTENTS:Text, SOURCE_CONTENTS:Id ,SNIPPET_ORDER
FROM temp_table
WHERE SOURCE_CONTENTS:Id IN ('5b7b930f-5715-4fa6-b85b-9e2253e2b389',
        '52e9d462-5aa2-4df2-9a33-3b59e03ea256',
        '92d278f8-2d44-41ce-8cfd-35feccfba29d',
        '69121af9-3270-488b-9335-70359859f9d6',
        '827011b6-fc8c-4749-89bd-91f376eaa554',
        'dd001bd6-f146-41e0-b5b3-6afb2bf37f17',
        'a4286c8f-f7a2-4b7d-84b0-e38b7cd93225' ) // Child values
;
```

Comment: Please can you provide the output you are expecting to see? Thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert on AWS Textract but I'm guessing it would be much easier to convert the Textract table(s) to csv and then import the csv files into Snowflake. AWS provide an example for producing the csv here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/examples-export-table-csv.html

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided sufficient context (table definition, exact output, etc) for another person to provide a comprehensive solution. I believe that this (or something similar to it) MIGHT be what you are seeking, but not sure...

```
WITH MY_TABLE AS (
  SELECT PARSE_JSON($1) AS SOURCE_CONTENTS
    FROM VALUES ($$
{
  "BlockType": "CELL",
  "ColumnIndex": 2,
  "ColumnSpan": 1,
  "Confidence": 99.87053680419922,
  "Geometry": {
    "BoundingBox": {
      "Height": 0.023682409897446632,
      "Left": 0.10847073048353195,
      "Top": 0.6578078269958496,
      "Width": 0.18180404603481293
    },
    "Polygon": [
      {
        "X": 0.10847073048353195,
        "Y": 0.6578078269958496
      },
      {
        "X": 0.2902747690677643,
        "Y": 0.6578078269958496
      },
      {
        "X": 0.2902747690677643,
        "Y": 0.6814902424812317
      },
      {
        "X": 0.10847073048353195,
        "Y": 0.6814902424812317
      }
    ]
  },
  "Id": "8f1d94e9-f936-4ea9-bae8-b3e0347c5411",
  "Page": 1,
  "Relationships": [
    {
      "Ids": [
        "5b7b930f-5715-4fa6-b85b-9e2253e2b389",
        "52e9d462-5aa2-4df2-9a33-3b59e03ea256",
        "92d278f8-2d44-41ce-8cfd-35feccfba29d",
        "69121af9-3270-488b-9335-70359859f9d6",
        "827011b6-fc8c-4749-89bd-91f376eaa554",
        "dd001bd6-f146-41e0-b5b3-6afb2bf37f17",
        "a4286c8f-f7a2-4b7d-84b0-e38b7cd93225"
      ],
      "Type": "CHILD"
    }
  ],
  "RowIndex": 1,
  "RowSpan": 1
}
    $$)
)
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(F.VALUE) AS Relationship_Ids
  FROM MY_TABLE T
      ,LATERAL FLATTEN(SOURCE_CONTENTS:"Relationships"[0]:"Ids") F
 WHERE SOURCE_CONTENTS:"BlockType"::VARCHAR = 'CELL'
 GROUP BY F.SEQ
;
```